# Verificar conexão de rede com Excel VBA

Tags: excel-vba

Tenho uma macro que salva na rede três planilhas de um arquivo em PDF.
Faz um loop e verifica quais planilhas vai salvar em PDF, e salva corretamente.
A macro trava ou dá erro quando a rede está ruim ou caiu, precisando utilizar a tecla ESC.

Como verificar antes se a rede está ativa e operacional?

Se a rede está mapeada como unidades, logicamente não achando é porque a rede está inativa ou o caminho não existe.

Uso On Error Resume Next uma linha antes do salvamento em PDF, e logo após If Err.Number > 0

```
Dim CaminhoArq As String
Dim NomeArq As String
CaminhoArq = ActiveSheet.Range("F2").Value
NomeArq = ActiveSheet.Range("F4").Value
If Right(CaminhoArq, 1) <> "\" Then
    CaminhoArq = CaminhoArq & "\"
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                    Filename:=CaminhoArq & NomeArq & ".pdf", _
                                    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Caminho da pasta não existe!", vbExclamation, "AAAAA"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

Não existindo o caminho a mensagem de erro é imediata.

Mas existindo o caminho e a rede estando inativa ou fraca, era para dar erro imediato e cair no IF Err.Number, mas o Excel trava e não responde, somente teclando ESC se consegue parar a macro.

Um código que achei na Internet, que gostaria de saber se funciona tanto para rede como para internet.

E continua o código somente se a rede estiver boa: estando ruim ou com algum problema ou inativa, para o código.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetGetConnectedStateEx Lib "wininet.dll" (ByRef lpdwFlags As Long, ByVal lpszConnectionName As String, ByVal dwNameLen As Integer, ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Long

Public Function IsInternetConnected() As Boolean
    IsInternetConnected = InternetGetConnectedStateEx(0, "", 254, 0)
End Function

Sub TestandoConexão()
    If IsInternetConnected = True Then
        MsgBox "Continua o código"
    Else
        MsgBox "Código interrompido"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Realizei testes com os dois códigos, **o primeiro** funciona perfeitamente e não consegui simular uma conexão fraca. Me conectei a um roteador com sinal fraco (1 barra de sinal sem fio) e mesmo assim salvou com sucesso, somente demorou mais. **No Segundo código**, ele funciona somente quando não há conexão com a rede, pode estar conectado ao roteador sem fio e depois retirar o cabo de internet e a função `IsInternetConnected` retornará `True`

Comment: Agradecido pelo teste.
Eu já desconfiava que era para a internet, e não para a rede.
Talvez um DIR com o caminho verifique se a rede está OK.
Não consegui um código em Excel VBA que verifique realmente a rede, e um código assim é que eu precisaria.
Talvez um código que faça um ping.
Será que existe?

Comment: Pelo contrário, ele verifica a rede. Se a rede estiver sem internet, porém o computador conectado nela, a função retorna `True`. Ela só retorna `False` se nenhuma rede estiver conectada.

Comment: Vamos ver se entendi:
Independente da internet estar ativa ou não;
- Se tiver rede a função retorna True.
- Se não tiver rede a função retorna False.
Ela só não verifica o ping, ou seja, não verifica se a rede está fraca ou não.

Comment: Obrigado!
Es estou desconfiado que eu mesmo estou fazendo tempestade em copo d'água.

Comment: Pode-se usar:
DIR
ou
FSO (FileSystemObject)
https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win003.htm

Comment: Ou um outro código que não não tenho como postar porque ultrapassa a quantidade de caracteres permitidos nos comentários.

Comment: Não faço a mínima ideia como se faz isso!

Comment: Há um FAQ [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/answering), mas não há tutorial de como responder. Basta escrever sua resposta na janela ao fim da página, em: **Sua Resposta** e depois clicar em Publique sua resposta. Verifique [como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas) e depois [aceite a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/75104). Sei que parece chato, mas não é perda de tempo. É para o bem da comunidade e assim que é o funcionamento da mesma, gerar conhecimento.